# How to manage consumers' sequential work using RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ to handle a lot of data. I have three types of consumers: `downloader, extracter` and `importer`. They must work sequentially in the order I mentioned above e.g. the `downloader` will download a bunch of files, pass to `extracter` and after extracting them the `importer` should import the info from the files into DB. My question is how can I implement this kind of functionality? Is this is a good approach to put the messages into `extracter`'s queue from `downloader` (`consumer`)? Or there is another solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a great case to use three separate queues. You'd have a `download` queue, an `extraction` queue, and an `import` queue.

The consumer of each queue would be responsible for putting a message on the next queue in the pipeline after it has finished its work.

So the workflow would look like this (queues prefixed with `queue.` to make them obvious):

```
??? -> queue.download
queue.download -> downloader -> download complete -> queue.extraction
queue.extraction -> extracter -> extraction complete -> queue.import
queue.import -> importer -> import complete -> ???
```

A couple of things to note:

- You'll need something to put messages into the `download` queue to kick things off.
- You can add other steps in the pipeline easily -- want to add a `compression` step (for example)? Have the downloader put messages into a `compression` queue, and then once that step is complete, put a message in the `extraction` queue.
- You can scale horizontally at any stage of the pipeline with ease. Downloading takes too long? Spin up more instances of `downloader` that pull messages off the same work queue.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Donut, I've already started to implement the functionality in the way you mentioned above. Thank you for the additional information and for the help!